# Wordpress REST API how to assign different categories to a post using Python requests library

Tags: python, wordpress, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api

I've created a python script to create & post articles to WordPress site but it seems that the category in post data isn't getting assigned to the posts and it always gets assigned to `uncategorized` category, I am looking to only assign 1 category to the posts.

Am I doing something wrong here? WordPress REST API Docs aren't really helpful.

Here's the post creator function:

```
# Post creator function
def create_post(inputTitleSent, outputText):
    randomAuthor = random.choice(authorList)
    
    post_status = "draft"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    post = {
        "title": inputTitleSent,
        "content": outputText,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": randomAuthor,
        "categories:": "6"
    }
    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
    return response
```

I've tried `"categories": 6` and I saw somewhere that it's suppose to be an array so I tried `"categories": [6]` and `"categories": ['6']` but still posts get assigned to `uncategorized` category.

Comment: You have a typo in `categories` array key, you've got a `:` in there. I've added an answer below stating that, but should be an easy and quick fix.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo because of editing and getting it ready to post but I  removed the other `:` and it still gets categorized under `uncategorized`

Answer (score 1):

Just came across your question and couple of things caught my attention!

> *"I saw somewhere that it's suppose to be an array so I tried "categories": [6] and "categories": ['6'] but still posts get assigned to uncategorized category."*

In addition to the typo that others already mentioned, I think **`the bug is in your headers`**.

I've had success with the following steps in the past:

### 1- Authentication and Proper Permissions

Before we send anything, we would need to make sure that we could authenticate ourselves with wordpress. If so, then we would need to make sure that we have proper permission(s) to create a post. Since you didn't talk about authentication/permissions errors, then I'm going to assume that you are able to authenticate yourself and have proper permissions to create a post and we are safe to move on to the next step!

### 2- Using proper `headers`

Make sure to set the proper headers! Since we're going to feed wordpress a `json` object, then our headers should contain this:

```js
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

### 3- Using `json` object as your post data/payload

I've had success with `json` objects in the past, so I would suggest that you use `json` object as your data/payload. And yes, categories should be an array of ids. In order to do so, you could do this:

```js
post = {
  "title": inputTitleSent,
  "content": outputText,
  "status": post_status,
  "author": randomAuthor,
  "categories": [
    6,
    5
  ], 
}
```

### 4- Posting your data to the `REST API`

You could either use this:

```py
response = requests.post(url, json=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
```

Or this:

```py
response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
```

Theoretically, both ways, should work!

---

So, your entire code would be something like this:

```py
# Post creator function
def create_post(inputTitleSent, outputText):

    post_status    = "draft"
    randomAuthor   = random.choice(authorList)

    headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }

    post = {
      "title": inputTitleSent,
      "content": outputText,
      "status": post_status,
      "author": randomAuthor,
      "categories": [
        6,
        5
      ],
    }

    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

    response = requests.post(url, json=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))

    # or 
    # response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
    
    return response
```

Answer (score -1):

So, Basically, there is a typo in your POST payload `"categories:": "6"` you can simply remove the `:` from the double quote

```py
def create_post(inputTitleSent, outputText):
    randomAuthor = random.choice(authorList)
    
    post_status = "draft"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    post = {
        "title": inputTitleSent,
        "content": outputText,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": randomAuthor,
        "categories": [6]  # Replace "categories:" with "categories"
    }
    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
    return response
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an additional `:` character in the `post` payload under `categories`:

```py
    post = {
        "title": inputTitleSent,
        "content": outputText,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": randomAuthor,
        "categories:": "6"
#                  ^
    }
```

Simply remove this and you'll get the results you're looking for:

```py
# Post creator function
def create_post(inputTitleSent, outputText):
    randomAuthor = random.choice(authorList)
    
    post_status = "draft"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    post = {
        "title": inputTitleSent,
        "content": outputText,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": randomAuthor,
        "categories": "6"
    }
    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username,wp_password))
    return response
```

Comment: So this answer is getting downvoted, probably because it seems wrong. It seems wrong because OP's question has been edited to remove the issue, which has effected lots of the answers, including this one. A new question probably should have been asked instead.